# Install latest java version in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

For some software, there is necessary to have java version 8 (or higher). I'm on ubuntu (16.04) and  I installed java so:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

now check java version: `java -version`

this gives: `openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)`

I dont get it, currently, there is java version 9(?) and I installed so old (1.8) version ?

*May be very stupid question, I'm very far from java and it's versioning*

Comment: Current Java version is 11. See linked question.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Thank you, one question also, now I need remove currently installed(old) version or new version will rewrite the old one ?

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove default-jre`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Thank You